# Count number of rows with conditions met in two columns

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have some Excel columns that look like this.

```
1774    David                    Not Upheld
1770    James                    Upheld
1771    David                    Upheld
1772    Sam                      Upheld
1768    Arthur                   Not Upheld
1769    James                    Upheld
```

How can I write an Excel formula for: count the number of rows with 'James' in column B, and 'Upheld' in column C?

I know how to do each of these conditions individually (using COUNTIF), but I'm not sure of the best way to combine them.

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `COUNTIFS` instead.

The COUNTIFS function, similar to COUNTIF  function, counts up the number of times data in two or more ranges of cells  meets multiple criteria.

The ranges must be of identical size, and the function only counts instances where the criterion for each range is met simultaneously - such as in the same row.

**Syntax**

```
COUNTIFS(range1, criteria1, range2, criteria2…)
```

Comment: You're more than welcome.