# Excel: Count occurence in multiple rows with condition

Tags: microsoft-excel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Count number of rows with conditions met in two columns](https://superuser.com/questions/166097/count-number-of-rows-with-conditions-met-in-two-columns)

I have a table in Excel that looks like this:

```
A                 1        2
B                 2
A                 1        2
C                 3        1
D                 1        3
A                 1        4
```

In column A i have a set of words. Some of them are repeated. In columns E and F I have two other sets. Now I want to count all events where A is in column A and 1 is in column E or F.

I tried something like this

```
=COUNTIF(A1:A6, "A", E1:F6, "1")
```

Bu this does not work. Any hints to to solve the problem?

Comment: Exact duplicate - [Count number of rows with conditions met in two columns](http://superuser.com/q/166097/97028)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, in order to have multiple conditions, you need to use `COUNTIFS` (an extra s).

You can then achieve what you want using

`=COUNTIFS(A:A,"A",E:E,1)+COUNTIFS(A:A,"A",F:F,1)-COUNTIFS(A:A,"A",E:E,1,F:F,1)`

which adds the contributions from E to that of F and subtracts the lines where both E and F are 1.

Adjust as needed.

**Edit:** For any number of columns, you may try:

`=SUMPRODUCT((A:A="A")*(E:F=1))`

Note that this will report two times a line which would have 1 in E and F.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to avoid this multiple +? Because I posted a simplified version of the problem here.

Comment: @RoflcoptrException: I edited my reply with an alternative.